# Bootique, running main example, server option not showing up

Tags: java

I'm following the [getting started guide](https://bootique.io/docs/0/getting-started/) of [bootique.io](https://bootique.io/) and I seem to run into something that might be related to my maven config or that might be related to recent changes in bootique.io which aren't covered in the getting started guide.

I've created a simple github project to follow along with the guide [here](https://github.com/rubin55/bootique-tryout) (git clone and mvn package, java -jar target/bootique-tryout-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar to run).

The getting started guide states that after compilation and running the jar, you should see a list of options that looks like this:

```
NAME
      com.foo.Application

OPTIONS
      -c yaml_location, --config=yaml_location
           Specifies YAML config location, which can be a file path or a URL.

      -h, --help
           Prints this message.

      -H, --help-config
           Prints information about application modules and their configuration
           options.

      -s, --server
           Starts Jetty server.
```

However, when I run my aforementioned follow-along version I see this:

```
NAME
      bootique-tryout-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar

OPTIONS
      -c yaml_location, --config=yaml_location
           Specifies YAML config location, which can be a file path or a URL.

      -h, --help
           Prints this message.

      -H, --help-config
           Prints information about application modules and their configuration
           options.
```

Notice the missing `-s, --server` option. What (obvious?) thing am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, after rumbling around the forums a little, I found out that this is due to some bootique specific settings when dealing with combined jars as produced by maven-assembly-plugin and maven-shade-plugin.

I removed my maven-assembly-plugin based jar-with-dependencies and replaced it with maven-shade-plugin, configured as follows:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I now `mvn clean package` and try to run the application, I am seeing the `-s, --server` option as expected:

```
NAME
      bootique-tryout-1.jar

OPTIONS
      -c yaml_location, --config=yaml_location
           Specifies YAML config location, which can be a file path or a URL.

      -h, --help
           Prints this message.

      -H, --help-config
           Prints information about application modules and their configuration
           options.

      -s, --server
           Starts Jetty server.
```

I've updated [my example project](https://github.com/rubin55/bootique-tryout) with the above fix.